# Java regex match all characters except

Tags: java, regex

What is the correct syntax for matching all characters except specific ones.

For example I'd like to match everything but letters `[A-Z] [a-z]` and numbers `[0-9]`.

I have

```
string.matches("[^[A-Z][a-z][0-9]]")
```

Is this incorrect?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, you don't need nested `[]` like that. Use this instead:

```
"[^A-Za-z0-9]"
```

It's all one character class.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to match anything but letters, you should have a look into [Unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop).

`\p{L}` is any kind of letter from any language

Using an uppercase "P" instead it is the negation, so `\P{L}` would match anything that is not a letter.

`\d` or `\p{Nd}` is matching digits

So your expression in modern Unicode style would look like this

Either using a negated character class

```
[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]
```

or negated properties

```
[\P{L}\P{Nd}]
```

The next thing is, `matches()` matches the expression against the complete string, so your expression is only true with exactly one char in the string. So you would need to add a quantifier:

```
string.matches("[^\p{L}\p{Nd}]+")
```

returns true, when the complete string has only non alphanumerics and at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
string.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost right. What you want is:

```
string.matches("[^A-Za-z0-9]")
```

Here's a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say that you want to make sure that no Strings have the _ symbol in them, then you would simply use something like this.

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("_");
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.matcher(stringName);
    if(!matcher.find()){
       System.out.println("Valid String");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Invalid String");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [negate character classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html):

```
"[^abc]"       // matches any character except a, b, or c (negation).
"[^a-zA-Z0-9]" // matches non-alphanumeric characters.
```