# Match until 0 or 1 is encounrtered

Tags: java, regex

Using below code I'm attempting to split the string "this is a test 1" into an array where first element contains the string "this is a test" and second element contains `1`.

```
final Pattern mp = Pattern.compile("/.+?(?=0|1)/");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(mp.split("this is a test 1")[0]));
```

When I execute this code the following is displayed :

```
[this is a test 1]
```

The regex `"/.+?(?=0|1)/"` is intended to match all strings until a 1 or 0 is encountered.

How to return Array("this is a test" , 1) ?

Update :

Should this also return same pattern :

```
final Pattern reg = Pattern.compile("/.+?(?=0|1)/");
    System.out.println(reg.matcher("this is a test 1").group(0));
```

It throws exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:536)
    at First.main(First.java:58)
```

But is essentially the same code but shorter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java regex match all characters except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207853/java-regex-match-all-characters-except)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pattern, but you actually need to create a `Matcher` to match a string with your pattern. An example can be found below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = ".+?(?=0|1)";
    final String string = "this is a test 1";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
    }
}
```

It appears that you want to have both elements, but your current regex does not allow for that. Try using `(.+?)([0-1])` Which will put both of these element inside groups. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String regex = "(.+?)([0-1])";
    final String string = "this is a test 1";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to call the `find()` function on your `Matcher` before you can extract any `group` from it

Answer (score 0):

Try the regex `(?=0|1)` to split the string to `this is a test` and `1`.

```
String mp="this is a test 1";
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(mp.split("(?=0|1)")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
    String text="this is a test 1";
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(text.split("(?=[01])")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to split on a space preceding `1|0`, so you can use a lookahead assertion:

```
String res = "this is a test 1 and 0 is it".split(" (?=(0|1))")
```

Which returns `{ "this is a test", "1 and", "0 is it" }`